# How to add variables that have been inputed by the user?

Tags: python, variables, addition

This is a short question, Here is my code:

```
flank2=raw_input("How many units are flanking from behind?: ")
if flank2 == '1':
    p1f1 = str(1.5)
if flank2 == '2':
    p1f1 = str(2)
else:
    p1f = str(1)
    p2f = str(1)

flank3=raw_input("How many units are flanking from the side?: ")
if flank3 == '1':
    p1f2 = str(1.25)
if flank3 == '2':
    p1f2 = str(1.5)
if flank3 == '3':
    p1f2 = str(1.75)
if flank3 == '4':
    p1f2 = str(2)
print p1f1 + p1f2
```

Lets say `p1f1 = 2` and `p1f2 = 1.5`. When I do this in python I get `21.5`, but I want to get `3.15`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't combine string, but convert to integers, put them together and take the result.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of all those `str()` conversions. When the variables are strings, `+` means concatenate rather than add. Leave them as floating point numbers.

```
flank2=raw_input("How many units are flanking from behind?: ")
if flank2 == '1':
    p1f1 = 1.5
if flank2 == '2':
    p1f1 = 2
else:
    p1f = 1
    p2f = 1   
flank3=raw_input("Hoaw many units are flanking from the side?: ")
if flank3 == '1':
    p1f2 = 1.25
if flank3 == '2':
    p1f2 = 1.5
if flank3 == '3':
    p1f2 = 1.75
if flank3 == '4':
    p1f2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add two strings together, they are concatenated, like this:

```
>>> '1.34' + '3.25'
'1.343.25'
```

`raw_input` returns a string. You should call `int()` on your `raw_input` before passing to `flank3`, and change your comparisons to numbers rather than strings.

When you add numbers together, they use addition rather than just concatenation.

So the new code would look like this:

```
flank2=int(raw_input("How many units are flanking from behind?: "))
if flank2 == 1:
    p1f1 = 1.5
if flank2 == 2:
    p1f1 = 2
else:
    p1f = 1
    p2f = 1
flank3=int(raw_input("Hoaw many units are flanking from the side?: "))
if flank3 == 1:
    p1f2 = 1.25
if flank3 == 2:
    p1f2 = 1.5 
if flank3 == 3:
    p1f2 = 1.75
if flank3 == 4:
    p1f2 = 2
print p1f1 + p1f2
```

Answer (score 0):

In all your assignments, you always specify `var = str(number)`. So in the end, you always end up with a string representation of the number. You’re better off just saving the numbers directly (and also use `elif` when you have multiple mutally exclusive if checks):

```
# for flank2
if flank2 == '1':
    p1f1 = 1.5
elif flank2 == '2':
    p1f1 = 2
else:
    p1f = 1
    p2f = 1

# and for flank3
if flank3 == '1':
    p1f2 = 1.25
elif flank3 == '2':
    p1f2 = 1.5
elif flank3 == '3':
    p1f2 = 1.75
elif flank3 == '4':
    p1f2 = 2
```

Now, if you add `p1f1` and `p1f2`, you are actually adding two numbers instead of adding two strings which results in a string concatenation. So this should give you the right result.

Note that, if `flank2` is neither `'1'` nor `'2'`, you will end up not setting `p1f1` at all, so that will raise an exception. You should definitely have a fallback value in the `else` part; and also do that for `flank3`.